# ZIP doesn't archive hidden file under the HOME

Tags: unix, zip, archive

Here is the directory structure of the folder I am trying to archive:

DIR STRUCTURE

```
HOME
HOME/.abc
HOME/FIRST
HOME/FIRST/.def
```

I am using simlpe `$PATCH/zip -r -l -x "bac*" abc.zip HOME/*`

One interesting thing I obseverved was it is skipping hidden folder directly under HOME and it zips the one under FIRST. What am I missing here? Is it any side effect of the options I am chosing ? Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*` is not interpreted by the zip utility, but rather expanded by the shell. Before the zip utility is executed, `*` is replaced by a space separated list of all the non-hidden files or directories.

You can prove this by replacing `$PATCH/zip` with `echo`, which will show the arguments that are actually passed to the program, after shell mangling.

---

If you set the environment variable `GLOBIGNORE` to `.:..`, not only will bash disable the matching of `.` and `..`, it has the nice effect of also automatically enabling 'dotglob', which matches the other hidden files without the need for `.*`, so you can just use `*` for everything.

For example, this should solve your problem:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.:..; $PATCH/zip -r -l -x "bac*" abc.zip HOME/*; unset GLOBIGNORE
```

Note that you cannot do this the short way, or in one command:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.:.. $PATCH/zip -r -l -x "bac*" abc.zip HOME/*
```

It seems that bash doesn't notice this until the next command.

Comment: now how can I specify the command so that it zips hidden files also in the HOME? HOME/.* doesn't work as it includes .. directory also

Comment: If you set the environment variable `GLOBIGNORE` to `.:..`, not only will bash disable the matching of `.` and `..`, it has the nice effect of also automatically enabling 'dotglob', which matches the other hidden files without the need for `.*`, so you can just use `*` for everything.

Answer (score 10):

```
zip archiveName -r .* -x "../*"
```

Trick si using .* and excluding ../*